# Accessing the error in Alamofire causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In my iOS app I have an UIVieController with a text field which sends a request each time the value is edited. The point is to show the user suggestions which are returned from the server as a JSON object.
I initially had all Alamofire requests run freely but to lighten the load (even though these requests were *very* lightweight) I added

```
didSet {
    oldValue?.cancel()
}
```

to my controller's `modalRequest` property, which stores the current request.

However now, my response handler throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) when trying to access the error in the closure. The code is as follows :

```
@IBAction func textValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentTextField = (sender as UITextField)

    if (currentTextField!.text != "") {
        modalRequest = Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://example.org/autocomplete/" + modalType.rawValue, parameters: ["term":currentTextField!.text]).responseJSON {(request, response, json, error) in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("Error: \(error)")
                println(request)
                println(response)
            } else {
                let oldCount = self.suggestions.count
                self.suggestions.removeAll()
                let suggestionJSON = JSON(json!)
                for s in suggestionJSON.arrayValue {
                    self.suggestions.append(s["name"].stringValue)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            }
        }
    } else {
        self.modalRequest?.cancel()
        self.suggestions.removeAll()
        self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

The weird and worrying part is that when I type quickly, thus canceling uncompleted requests, everything goes swiftly (pun intended), meaning that the console logs all error's as cancelled. However if the text I input contains a space and a previous request is cancelled through quick typing, the logger tries to print the error but throws the EXC_BAD_ACCESS, **even though it's in optional binding**! Shouldn't that ensure that value isn't nil so at least exists?

Have you ever encountered this?

Thank you for your time!

**NB**: deleting the line does of course work but I might want to add error handling in the future and this bug is really bugging me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as to continue my previous comment on cnoon's answer : I replaced `NSLog()` with `println()` and voilà! It works! No more EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

However I don't know why it was a bad access. Is `NSLog` somehow so slow or does it not copy the value so it's nil when it finally logs? I have no idea...

**EDIT** : As I said in my question, it *only* crashed when the query contained a space. And error.description, which is added as-is to the string, contains the URL String. A space encoded in a URL is "%20" so `NSLog` interpreted it as the string formatter `%2`, so it went looking for the second optional argument in `NSLog` which of course, **did not exist**! Haha! So to really beautifully fix it I replaced the line with :

```
NSLog("Error: %@", error)
```

Now it's a beautiful log, without any hiccups! That's what I get for copying some default code which combines Swift string interpolation with Objective-C string formatting!

Comment: Ha! Definitely wouldn't have ever figured that one out from the info provided. Glad you got to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting caught in two possible race conditions.

1. The deinit of the previous modalRequest
2. A weakify / strongify problem with self

The following should solve both race conditions.

```
@IBAction func textValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentTextField = (sender as UITextField)

    if (currentTextField!.text != "") {
        modalRequest?.cancel()
        modalRequest = nil

        modalRequest = Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://example.org/autocomplete/" + modalType.rawValue, parameters: ["term":currentTextField!.text])
        modelRequest.responseJSON { [weak self] request, response, json, error in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                if let error = error {
                    NSLog("Error: \(error)")
                    println(request)
                    println(response)
                } else {
                    let oldCount = self.suggestions.count
                    self.suggestions.removeAll()
                    let suggestionJSON = JSON(json!)
                    for s in suggestionJSON.arrayValue {
                        self.suggestions.append(s["name"].stringValue)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        self.modalRequest?.cancel()
        self.suggestions.removeAll()
        self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

If this ends up working, then I'd suggest moving the following:

```
modalRequest?.cancel()
modalRequest = nil
```

into a `willSet` instead of the `didSet`.

```
willSet {
    modalRequest?.cancel()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I had to edit it a bit ("?" when calling responseJSON, replacing self with strongSelf, etc.) and I tried it and it did _not_ fix the issue. Which then led me to think that it was really weird that my temporary fix (commenting the Error line) worked without throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS for the two println() lines. So I came up with my solution below.

Comment: And thank you very much because I didn't know of `willSet` (which I didn't keep because even though it worked, calling `.cancel()` threw a warning about trying to set the value in it's own `willSet`, because it was going to be overwritten, so I kept didSet because it also works and doesn't warn). And I also got to learn about weak/strong variables (which I've never given much thought about before).

Comment: Okay cool. I would only try `.cancel()` in the `willSet` closure. That makes sense that you can't set it to nil. Did you end up figuring out your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` then?

Comment: Yep, through seeing in which cases NSLog would throw an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and then I found my solution!

Comment: Good explanation. In Swift 3 you can substitute `if let strongSelf = self { ... }` with just `guard let strongSelf = self else { return }`